# Error on javascript code :Uncaught ReferenceError: **** is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm quite new to javascript and I'm trying to code for a website.
I got some error during my work and i still can't figure out what's happening, please let me know if you have any idea.
My javascript code works just fine until I created this function

```
function setFilter(filter){
  $(".filtre").onclick(function(){
    var theClass = this.className;
    var mainClass = theClass.split(' ')[0]
    console.log(mainClass)
    for (i=0; i< filter['filters'].length;i++){
              for (j=0;j< filter['filters'][i]['value'].length;j++){
                if ( filter['filters'][i]['value'][j]["id"] === theClass){
                    filter['filters'][i]['value'][j]["selected"] = true;
            }}}
})}
```

I want the code to modify the key 'selected' of my object when the element is clicked. So I pick the clicked element class name to identify which line of my object I should change. Then I do a loop on the whole object to get the line that as a similar keyid name than the CSS class of my element. then on that line, it should change the selected key from False to True.

exemple of my object :

```
filter = {'filters': [

  {'type_': 'designOutline',
   'label': 'Design Outline',
   'value': [{'id': 'full', 'label': 'Full', 'selected': false},
    {'id': 'outline', 'label': 'Outline', 'selected': false}]}]}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: add `scripts` just before the `</body>` end tag ?

Comment: did you call setFilter?  setFilter() -> like this as it will addeventlistener on .filtre class.

Comment: yes it just does the same error :/ @AlwaysHelping

Comment: onclick is not a jquery method. it should be click.

Comment: @deepak yes sorry i first used .click() but i saw it gave me this error so i tried several option. I should still write it back as .click()

Comment: can you provide working example so that I can have look?

Comment: I guess when you are comparing the id it should be againt mainclass rather than "theClass"

Comment: Provide more information if you need help.

Comment: I don't think it's the cause of the error but the scripts should be before the closing </body> tag, otherwise it's not valid html

Comment: @deepak thank you I made this mistake and now its working ! yes you are right thats why i created this variable ...

Comment: @JonasGrumann thank you I'll modify it